# Tomcat returns http response code 400

Tags: http, rest, tomcat, httpurlconnection

I was googling for a long time, but still can't find a solution to my case.

My Tomcat sometimes returns an exception :

```
Error in postRequest(): Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:80/CITIUS2/webresources/entities.personainterna/
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it returns this exception, so I really don't know what is the reason...

Connection function:

```
public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String responseXML = null;

    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        byte[] requestXML = urlParameters.getBytes();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(requestXML.length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");


        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        // Send the String that was read into postByte.
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(requestXML);
        out.close();

        // Read the response and write it to standard out.
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String temp;
        String tempResponse = "";

        //Create a string using response from web services
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tempResponse = tempResponse + temp;
        }
        responseXML = tempResponse;
        br.close();
        isr.close();
    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in postRequest(): Secure Service Required");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in postRequest(): " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return responseXML;
}
```

@ Edit:

In general build is successful, there are no errors, only this one in the Apache Tomcat's output window.

Rest method:

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Response create(Personainterna entity) {
    try {
        getJpaController().create(entity);
        return Response.created(URI.create(entity.getPersonaId().toString())).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Response.notModified(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: add the stacktrace and also you REST method accepting the call.